# Linux software to query the Skyhook database

Tags: ubuntu, wireless-networking, mac-address

I'm a Ubuntu user. I'm looking for some software which will query the Skyhook database with the MAC addresses of all the Wi-Fi hotspots in range of my computer and display the results. I'm looking for something I can install on my machine. Code samples would be good too.

Answer (score 1):

http://www.skyhookwireless.com/developers/sdk.php
http://loki.com/how